# How can I identify on linux how many sockets/cpus are installed on the hardware?

Tags: linux, cpu

For Oracle licensing topics I need to identify how many sockets and cpus are actually installed on the hardware. On windows this information can be found by the cmd command “systeminfo”.

Answer (score 3):

You can find out it from cpuinfo file.

Run below mentioned command to find number of cpu socket.

```
grep "physical id"  /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: Notes to self: a) `sort -u` deduplicates (each CPU thread - not just physical core - has a separate entry in `cpuinfo` file), b) wc -l counts the lines (here: reporting the number of rows with "physical id")